# Linear Algebra subspaces proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Assume that $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $T : V \to W$ is linear.
Let $V'$ be a subspace of $V$ . Prove that $W' = T(V')$ is a subspace of $W$ (here
$T(V') = \{T(v)\, |\, v \in V'\}$).

I have been working on this proof for a few days and have come up with almost nothing, save a few definitions that I know I need. When it comes to proofs I just don't know what to do. If someone could give me an idea of how to go about proving this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

$T:V\to W$ means that $\forall v\in V,\,T(v)\in W$. Doesn't it means that $T(V')\subset W$?

Then recall that $S$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ if and only if:

i) $0\in S$ ($0$ is the identity element of the abelian group $(V,+)$).

ii) $\forall u,v\in S,\,v+w\in S$

iii)$\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{F},\forall u\in S,\,\alpha. u\in S$ ($\mathbb{F}$ is the field where we take from the scallar elements)

So use these three points to show that $T(V')$ is a subspace of $W$. Use the properties of the linear application $T$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. That first line was exactly what I needed; it made me literally face-palm for not realizing it myself. I tend to get flustered looking at a block of words and equations like this one, trying to figure out whats going on. Thanks alot.

Comment: The same think happens for me sometimes, to not be able to notice easy thinks. You're welcome! And welcome to stackexchange.com !